# AWS CodePipeline: source action No connection exists with the ARN

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm setting up a CodePipeline, and I created an action to fetch the source from GitHub.
If ı created new codepipeline everthings look fine also on GitHub's  and aws side. I gave the AmazonS3FullAccess for Codepipeline.

[AmazonS3FullAccess for Codepipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BT668.png)

However , after around 24 hours , my codepipeline source action is breaking.I am taking this error.

> ResourceNotFoundException

> No connection exists with the ARN: arn:aws:codestar-connections:eu-west-1:574387060469:connection/9e79fd78-9e52-476d-9d43-c4f894a556e5

I do not want to  create regularly a new codePipeline . How can ı fix this problem for one time?

Answer (score 0):

You want to edit the `Source` stage in your pipeline so you can update the connection to a GitHub version 2 connection (if you use GitHub as your Source) - you can also select any option available if you use another source provider.

1. From your pipeline press the `Edit` button at the top left of the view
2. From the `Edit` view, look at your `Source Stage` and press the `Edit Stage` button.
3. From the `Edit Stage` view you then need to add a new Action for the source connection - press the `Add Action` button next
4. Next enter an `Action Name` and select your `Action Provider` that you can find under the `Source` section in the drop down list.
5. Under the `connection` heading select the connection you want to use if you have created it or press the `Connect to GitHub` button to create a new connection.
6. Next select the `Repository Name` and the `Branch` you want to pull the source from when youre ready to deploy new versions.
7. `Start the pipeline on source code change` can be selected if you want to automatically deploy on every push to source.
8. Your output artifact can be named `Source`
9. Finally press `Save` to update your pipeline source stage.

Your pipeline connection should now be updated to use the new connection.